# Javascript Touch Force on iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I have implemented reading the touch force for haptic touchscreen as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/force

If I test in chrome debug tools on a PC (set to mobile) then it will register the force as 1 (as far as I can tell there's no way to simulate a different pressure). So I know the code it correct.

However on my iPhone XR which does have a haptic screen it always registers as 0.

The compatibility table says Safari on iOS support it, and I haven't been able to find anything that says you need to request the user permission for the feature (like you would with device orientation).

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

on [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=touch%20force) you have more details on support for iOs Safari, please check your safari iOs version is **>= 14.5**.